# How to do "WHERE" in Sequelize, but EXCLUDE nested Model?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

There are two models: User and Client.

```
Client.hasMany(User);
User.belongsTo(Client);
```

Next, I'm doing:

```
User.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Client,
        where: {
            id: “1”
        }
    }]
});
```

This code works fine, but includes Client model in final output with all attributes. How can I still do “where” statement, but exlcude Client model at all?

Comment: To be clear, you still want to query based on the client but you just don't need that object back in the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that 2 ways

```
User.findAll({
    attributes : ['User.*'] // might be user.* or users.* . as per your query genetaion
    include: [{
        model: Client,
        where: {
            id: "1"
        }
    }]
});

//OR

{
  attributes: {
    include: [], // define columns that you want to show
    exclude: [] // define columns that you don't want 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a little janky and not *really* what you want but I had a similar situation and I solved it like this.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  User.findAll({
    include: [{
      model: Client,
      where: {
        id: "1"
      }
    }]
  }).then(users => {
    users.forEach(u => u.client = null);
    resolve(users);
  }).catch(e => {
    reject(e);
  });
});
```

So your wrapping the request in a promise and grading the result of the querying, removing the property you don't want (I just nulled it out but you could get more creative mapping the object if wanted), then return the object as you like.

**TLDR;**
You can't (afaik). You have to do something like this if your **absolutely** do not want the client in the response.